# How can I download a web page by using Wget?

Tags: php, linux, html, wget

Firstly, i want download the web page: http://acm.sgu.ru/problem.php?contest=0&problem=161
I try to use the command：

```
wget -o 161.html http://acm.sgu.ru/problem.php?contest=0&problem=161
```

But it not work!
Anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The URL you are providing to `wget` contains characters that have special meaning in the shell (`&`), therefore you have to escape them by putting them inside single quotes.
2. Option `-o file` is used to log all messages to the provided file.

   If you want the page to written to the provided file use option `-O file` (capital `O`).

Try:

```
wget -O 161.html 'http://acm.sgu.ru/problem.php?contest=0&problem=161'
```

Comment: Oh,you are right! Thanks! I write the URL in file url.txt,and use the command:wget -o 161.html -i url.txt. And it not save the webpage in file 161.html. The webpage save in file named problem.php@contest=0&problem=161.